# Datetime field won't update Entity Framework SQL Server 2012 and Web API

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, asp.net-web-api

Ok, I am pulling my hair out.

I have Entity Framework and I'm trying to call `SaveChanges()` and it's not updating the datetime column.

I have tried changing the entity state, removing the milliseconds, changing precision etc.

I ran SQL Server Profiler to find exactly what is being sent to SQL Server. Here is the code that makes the change and the profile log.

```
PRICE currentPrice = db.PRICES.Find(id);
currentPrice.PRICE_AMOUNT = dec;

currentPrice.PRICE_TS = DateTime.Now;

db.Entry(currentPrice).State = EntityState.Modified;

db.SaveChanges();
```

SQL Server profile log

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[PRICES]
SET [PRICE_AMOUNT] = @0, [PRICE_BIZ_ID] = @1, [PRICE_SOLDOUT] = @2
WHERE ([PRICE_ID] = @3)
SELECT [PRICE_TS]
FROM [dbo].[PRICES]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [PRICE_ID] = @3',N'@0 decimal(4,2),@1 int,@2 bit,@3 int',@0=2.48,@1=1,@2=0,@3=1
```

It completely skips the change in price! I don't know why its doing a select at all!

Please help!

EDIT:
Here is my Prices Class. I'm using Database first EDMX

```
public partial class PRICE
{
    public int PRICE_ID { get; set; }
    public decimal PRICE_AMOUNT { get; set; }
    public int PRICE_BIZ_ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime PRICE_TS { get; set; }
    public bool PRICE_SOLDOUT { get; set; }

    public virtual BUSINESS BUSINESS { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand - the SQL ***IS*** updating the `PRICES` table, and it ***IS*** setting the `PRICE_AMOUNT` column...... what is missing?? Also: what **data types** are your columns in the `PRICES` table?

Comment: Can you please show the definition of price?

Comment: the `PRICE_TS` column isn't updating, that's his problem.  How are you using EF (Code First, etc)?  Can you show the `PRICES` class?

Comment: `db.Entry(currentPrice).State = EntityState.Modified;` isn't needed, as soon as you change an entity's properties, the context tracks that change and marks it modified.

Comment: Is this a full instance server or LocalDb?

Comment: I have edited my original to reflect data needed. Also this is a full SQL server 2012 instance.

Comment: Originally i didn't use the entitystate thing. I've been reading so many SO questions and none of them seem to answer my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part

```
SELECT [PRICE_TS]
```

reveals that you had mapped `PRICE_TS` as a computed column, i.e. in the edmx designer you had set its `StoreGeneratedPattern` property to `Computed`.

The value of a computed column is always fetched from the database after insert and update statements, because the database generates the value, and EF wants the entity object to represent the database content correctly.

By removing and re-adding the entity the property reverted to the default.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to believe this...
I added another table to archive this data to show graphs later on in prices and found that the datetime in that table would update just fine! it was an exact copy of the other. 
So i deleted the prices table out of the EDMX, added it back and built it. Now it works. Microsoft at its best there. Hopefully this helps someone if they have the same issue as me.

There goes 4+ hours of my life.